# how to print data 1 Collectionview of 2 different cell

Tags: ios, swift

2 Array or 2 different Cell and 1 CollectionView -  **How to print in Collectionview**

**1. array1.count = 70
2. array2.count = 100**

**how to print data  1 Collectionview of 2 different cells.**

please say Ans...

Comment: You have 2 kinds of cell, not only 2 cells? One array per section? It's unclear what's your final output should look like.

Comment: Can you share your code or share a picture that explains what do you want?